# Apple Internet Reachability fails to work

Tags: iphone, ios8, afnetworking-2, reachability

I have tested a reachability code provided by apple but it fails in following scenerio. Same is tested by AFNetworking library 2.0, and it also fails:

*1). Turn on wifi and Run code.
2). Turn off you your data connection just by unplugging your cable from device, but keep in mind you have a wifi signal on your iphone device.
3). Now run code and it will say internet unavailable.
4). Now connect cable again in wifi device.*

Now run your code again and it will says that your network is unavailable, although you can check safari is safely browsing. 
You have to restart your iphone again to have a normal codition.

Note: it fails only when you check with this scenerio. it works fine with cellular network.

What can i do ? is it an apple bug ?

Comment: Please show your "non working" code.

Comment: Check apple's own reachability code.Its actually problematic.

Comment: If you need more details. it will add here.